# Excel "COUNTA(UNIQUE())" returning seemingly inconsistent results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count unique cells above the current cell using the formula `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW())))` but it always returns 1. To search for the problem, I removed `COUNTA()` and got the expected result, and alternatively replaced the `ROW()` with a literal number and got the expected result. I don't understand why the first formula would output 1 instead of 3 when these other two work as expected.

[image: Excel sheet formulas]

Comment: UNIQUE() will include a `0` if there's a blank amongst the cells included in the range, therefore returns 1. You need to apply an extra filter to the range, like `=ROWS(Unique(Tocol(A1:Index(A:A,row()),1)))`

Comment: Instead of using a volatile function i would go for the one with `INDEX()` also i dont understand  why you are taking the long route when it could be easily done using `=ROWS(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A:A,1)))` also, let me make you clear why you are getting one and not the specific output, this is because of the use of `ROW()` function inside `INDIRECT()` if you place the formula in cell `B7` you would get `3` if below you will get `4`, while `B5` or `B4` it will be `2` and `1` respectively. Try to evaluate this part of the formula `INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW())` it takes up the data till the corresponding row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `COUNTA()`is counting only first result here. Try-

```
=COUNTA(--UNIQUE(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW())))
```

[image]

Comment: You could also mention using `ROWS` instead of `COUNTA` since we have used it so many times.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes, There are also few other methods but I have shown using `COUNTA()`.

Comment: Thanks! But then I'm curious why it does sometimes work. Why does `COUNTA(UNIQUE(A1:A7))` give 3 without the --?

Comment: I can't explain exact reason but I found few formula can't take dynamic full array as input. It take only first result. However if we use `--` to suppress results then it work well with those formulas. You may search on google for more.